# How to interact with php in two different server

Tags: php, cross-domain

I am trying to work on a project that can generate an images for bunch of pdf files.

The script I am running and the web interface are on `server A`.

I have the web page in `server A` like the following

```
pdf a
pdf b
pdf c
pdf d

create pdf images button.
```

After I hit the button, the images will be generated and display in the web page.

However, those actually pdf files are in `server B`.

The `php` script to generate `pdf` images is in `server B` as well. I am not sure how to accomplish this. Can anyone give me a hint for it? Thanks so much!

Comment: Does server B have web interface? If no how you cen connect with it (use NFS, SSH) ?

Comment: that is my question. Server B has no web interface. every interface is built in server A

Comment: which operating system are on your servers?

Comment: linux ubuntu is server a and amazon cloud is server b. Amazon cloud already has php installed.

Comment: What is the reason you haven't install web server on server b? If you install web server you can easy connect to it from any place and get results.

Comment: We don't want to do that because the requirement is to do everything on Server A not Cloud.

Comment: You can use amason web server only as API to it pdf functions. You can use SSH to connect to amazon server and execute some command if it can take ssh connections.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28400/discussion-between-flyingcat-and-victor)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe put them as jobs in a database, and then have each server query that database to pull 'requests'

There are some good tools for building job daemons that you can use to accomplish this kind of thing.

If this isn't what you are looking for, forgive me for misunderstanding the question!